# CSS cross inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In CSS, is there a way to refer to property value like width of a container div tag from one of its contained elements to create a dynamic relationship between the two.  Here is some code to illustrate my intent:

```
<div id="settingz" style="position:absolute; width: 350px; height: 300px;">
<span style="position:absolute;  left:inherit parent width; margin-left:-30px; top:6px;" >
        <img id="exportRedX" src="/static/RedX2.png" />
    </span>
(/div>
```

Notice the silly attempt `left:inherit parent width;`  That is the best way for me to convey what I'm trying to do.  I want to tie the image to a position relative to the div's width.  I know about the `align="right"` but that does not really do what `margin-left` can contribute to the `left:  ...` inheritance.

Any help is appreciated...

DK

Comment: No, you cannot do that.

Comment: What you should be able to do is just let them float next to each other, in a common container.

Comment: @Bergi  That complicates things a bit, but I see your point, using position:relative.  Good idea, though it complicates things a bit.  I found an interesting solution.  I will publish it after I get more inputs.

Comment: I think a simple `float:left` is faaaaaar less complicated than trying to create dynamic inheritance in CSS.

Comment: @zessx  Both float:left and float:right make the image to go far to the left, but I thought that you were right.  I don't understand why float:right does not do it?  Thank you for the suggestion, however...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with pure CSS, however you can use CSS preprocessors such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to achieve similar things by using variables and mix-ins.

Comment: very interesting reply.  I never heard of these...  Must investigate...  Thank you for your input...

Comment: Wow!  SASS and LESS are very impressive @rink.attendant.6 .  Thank you for the light...

Comment: @DKean: Yes, but don't forget they're not dynamic and serverside only.

Comment: @Bergi I think that LESS is client side too!

Comment: @DKean: Oh, right. But only in modern browsers, i.e. not where you would really need it in lack of CSS3 features.

Comment: @Bergi You are correct and that is why  I have it on the back burner!  But it is good to know, however.  Thank you for your kind participation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much for the help.  SASS and LESS seem to be impressive and I will dabble with them later.  For now the solution I found, which answers my need is as follows:

```
<span style="position:absolute;  left: 100% ; margin-left:-30px;" >
    <img id="exportRedX" src="/static/RedX2.png" />
</span>
```

This hugs the right side and allows me to adjust the relative distance from the right as well.

The solution lies in `left: 100% ; margin-left:-30px;`.  That makes the hugging dynamic.

Your time lent to help me is very appreciated, guys!

Thank you all,

DKean